# Cast video to Samsung TV with Google Cast API

Tags: google-cast, smartview

I need to cast video to Samsung TVs. My app inegrates the [Google Cast API](https://developers.google.com/cast) and is able to cast video to Chromcast devices. Is there any way to send video to Samsung's Smart View with this API? Is there any other way to do it?